# How to list all keys on cedar (double-array trie)

Tags: c++, c, trie

I'm using [this](http://www.tkl.iis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~ynaga/cedar/) library to store a lot of strings. How to get all keys from this library?

There's only way to get all values, `dump` function [line](https://code.hackerearth.com/5f0250R) `228`:

```
union { int i; value_type x; } b;
size_t num = 0, from = 0, p = 0;
char key[256] = {0};
for (b.i = begin (from, p); b.i != CEDAR_NO_PATH; b.i = next (from, p)) {
  // b.x is the value
  // which variable that contains `len` and `to` 
  //  that I should pass to suffix function?
  suffix(key, len, to);
}
```

It stated on the documentation that to retrieve the key, we must call `suffix` function:

```
void suffix (char* key, const size_t len, size_t to)
```

> Recover a substring key of length = len in a trie that reaches node to. key must be allocated with enough memory by a user (to store a terminal  character, len + 1 bytes are needed).

But how to know the `len` and the `to` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Found it, the `p` is the `len`, and `from` is `to`:

```
char key[256] = {0};
for (b.i = begin(from, p); b.i != CEDAR_NO_PATH; b.i = next(from, p)) {
  // b.x is the value
  suffix(key, p, from); // key now should hold the key
}
```